# Python regular expression not identifying \% and \^

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to identify invalid metacharacters that are of the set {@,$,!,%,&,^}.
Here is the Python3 code:

```
import re
def _getHTML(input):
        if re.search(r'(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%\^)', input) is not None:
            raise Exception('Invalid metacharacter found:(@,$,!,%,&,^)')
        else:
            print("passed")
```

However, _`getHTML('eee e rwer %')` results in 'passed' when it should throw an error because of the '%'.

Comment: Are you sure there are _no typos_ in the regex?

Comment: Your regexp is missing a vertical bar between `\%` and `\^`

Comment: regexp should be `(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^)`

Comment: You just need this regex: `[!@#$^%]`

Comment: Yes, can't believe I missed that looking at it for an hour! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `|` (OR) after `\%` in the Regex pattern:

```
(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^)
```

But rather than OR-ing and needness grouping (as you are not referring it afterwards), you can use the character class:

```
[!@#$%^]
```

you can get rid of the `\` escapes as well inside `[]`.

Comment: How come I don't need to escape the metacharacters in the character class?

Comment: @HarisIrshad Because that's how character classes work. I would suggest you to go through a good Regex doc.

Comment: Just adding, [^!@#$%] this will mean the opposite of what you intend to since [^] means a not for things that follow. Always good to be explicit and escape meta-characters even when its not necessary.